# Get form action and method from form submit event

Tags: javascript

I have the below code which intercepts the submit event from a form. How can I get the path and method from the event (i.e. the `action` and `method` attributes from the form)? I've tried logging out the event and looking through it's properties but it is massive and I couldn't find them, and the Mozilla docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubmitEvent) just lists one property and says the rest inherits from `Event`. If is not possible I assume I can just get the values directly from the form element, but I would prefer to get them from the event because I assume it does extra things like expands a relative URL in the `action` attribute.

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form");
form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either access it from the `form` variable you created, or you can access the event's "base" target, i.e. the element the listener was attached to, using [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget).

Here is an example:

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form");
form.addEventListener("submit", event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  const target = event.currentTarget;
  
  console.log(target.method, target.action);
  console.log(form.method, form.action);
  console.log(form === target)
});
```

```html
<form action="#/action-reaction" method="post">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```